# Android: Trouble with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android development and I have been trying make an application that allows users to flip either to the left or right to change fragments. I'm using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter for this.

I first, in a for loop, created each fragment separately in the main activity's OnCreate() method and added them to the FragmentManager **fManager**.

```
for(Day day: days){
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    this.fManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.pager, fragment).commit();
}
fManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

I then set up UI elements and set the ViewPager's adapter like so

```
this.setUpUI();
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

The problem is is that I keep encountering this exception **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Already Added...**

I am very confused as to what is going on because the only place I add fragments to the FragmentManager is in the for-loop above. Do FragmentStatePagerAdapter's do something in the background that might cause this issue or am I not implementing my ScreenSlidePagerAdapter correctly?

Here is my code for the **ScreenSlidePagerAdapter** class:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public FragmentManager fm;
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = fm.getFragments().get(position);
        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fm.getFragments().size();
    }
}
```

Input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that unless you are creating a lot of fragments, do not use FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Extend FragmentPagerAdapter instead. This is better practice. More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show create the fragments inside getItem(pos) method of Adapter. The adapter internally use the FragmentManager that you provide in constructor. 
Some what like this:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        return f;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` already adds the fragments to your `Activity` (in the `getItem()` method). Try to remove that for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the Fragment that is already in the `FragmentManager` and when you return it, the PagerAdapter tries to add it, but it is already there.

You don't have to add the fragments to the `FragmentManager` yourself. That's the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`'s job, that's why it receives a `FragmentManager` reference. You only have to create and return the fragments in `getItem()` and the PagerAdapter will add the fragments to the `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do what you are trying like this:

```
public class FragmentSliderAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public FragmentSliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        list.add(new LoginFragment());
        list.add(new SignupFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return list.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


}
```

Using list is cleaner and a good approach, since you can control what fragments are added to your adapter.
On the activity that uses the adapter, I just do this:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
adapter = new FragmentSliderAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the activity xml I do:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

See if it helps !